# Object retrieved from ioc turned null after JMX method invoker

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, jmx

I am using Spring 3.1 as standalone app.

I have some wierd situation and I guess I am missing something.

I have class which has method that I have exposed via JMX console.
that method is invoking a method via bean.

that bean I am initializing in advaned.
the wierd thing that after i am invoking the method via the jmx console the bean instance turn to be null.

Thats the JMX bean which is exposed:

```
public class TriggerBean implements IJmxTriggerBean
{
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TriggerBean.class);

    FeedListenerBean fe = null;

    public void start()
    {
        try
        {
            // init();
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(FixGWConstants.LOG4J_PATH);
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(FixGWConstants.APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML);
            fe = (FeedListenerBean) context.getBean("FeedListenerBean");
            doTheListen();

        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            logger.error(t);
            System.out.println(t);
        }

    }

        //thats the method being exposed by jmx. pay attention that fe object has been   initialized before by the start()
    public void doTheListen()
    {
        fe.listen();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//config.properties");
        try
        {
            Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            String log4jPath = props.getProperty("LOG4J_PATH");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am testing it via standalone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
protected TriggerBean trigger = new Trigger();
trigger.start();
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"


    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Must for auto wiring 
    <context:annotation-config />
    -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fixgw.beans">
    </context:component-scan>



    <!-- start a JMX Server -->
    <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="FeedListenerBean" class="com.fixgw.beans.FeedListenerBean">
    </bean>

    <bean id="TriggerBean" class="com.fixgw.test.TriggerBean">
    </bean>





    <bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="Server:name=HttpAdaptor">
                    <bean class="mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor">
                        <property name="port" value="8000" />
                        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0" />
                        <property name="processor">
                            <bean class="mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.XSLTProcessor" />
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </entry>
                <entry key="bean:name=TriggerBean" value-ref="TriggerBean" />

            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="listeners">
            <list>
                <!--
                    let the HttpAdapter be started after it is registered in the
                    MBeanServer
                -->
                <bean class="com.fixgw.jmx.HttpAdaptorMgr">
                    <property name="mbeanServer" ref="mbeanServer" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I first using start() the object fe is doing great. 
but after invoking doTheListen( via JMX the object fe remind null(although it has already been initialized before)

any idea?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: Can you log fe in your init code?

Comment: The init code is not relevant. but when first I invoke start() fe works perfectly fine. [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'FeedListenerBean'

Comment: ah, sorry, I meant the start() method. Just wanted to make sure the fe instance was being initialized on startup.